# Mac Caps Lock Sign on password input?

Tags: passwords, capslock

i'm not sure if its just me. i noticed that on the mac or maybe its just in chrome in general but when you press down the caps lock key on a password input box a little grey notification image pops up. the problem is this covers an important feature on my site.

Is there a way to tell it where to pop up? i have seen it pop up in different place such as inside the input field on other sites.

Would appreciate if anyone has any ideas or knows how to sort it. thanks

Comment: You're talking about the big up-arrow icon? I see it in Chrome, Safari, Keychain Access, but not Firefox. But it's always in the input box. Where is it popping up for you?

Comment: yea thats the thing im talking about. its popping up on the outside of the password box about 10px over to the right.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? I can't make it appear outside the box. I even tried making a really small password box `<input type="password" size="2"/>` and it still put the icon in the box.